# Knockout ViewModel, call view model from array of models into 'with' data-bind

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, viewmodel, with-statement, viewdata

This is my code, the second shows where the compiler complains, only says 'Syntax Error'

```
<div id="@ViewData["ID"]" class="DataGrid" data-bind="with: _gridModels["@ViewData["ID"]"]">

<div id="@ViewData["ID"]" class="DataGrid" data-bind="with: _gridModels     Error > [ < Here    "@ViewData["ID"]"]">
```

This is where I want to create an array of view models, so that the model can be re-used by the same partial view rendered multiple times on the same page, where a `with` `data-bind` could be used to pull only the viewModel created for the specific partial view in which it was created.

```
var _gridModels = [];
_gridModels["@ViewData["ID"]"] = new GridModel();
function GridModel() {
    // etc
}
ko.applyBindings(_gridModels["@ViewData["ID"]"], document.getElementById("@ViewData["ID"]"));
```

Comment: Do you need to escape inner double-quotes?

Comment: Tried combinations of escaping and not-escaping " and '

Answer (score 0):

Made a workaround

```
function ThisGridModel()
{
    return _gridModels["@ViewData["ID"]"];
}

<table data-bind="with: ThisGridModel()">
```